# Import Jar Library from Classpath in Scala

Tags: scala, import, jar, classpath

So I have tried to import a library to Scala which comes as a Jar.
I have been looking for solutions online for half the day today, and at least got to the stage where I can successfully add the jar to the class path.

But when I try to import it now, it doesn't seem to work. I get an error: not found. I am working in an anaconda environment and I would like to load the package without using sbt.

This is the code I run:

```
scala> :require tinyir.jar
```

which returns

```
Added '/my/directory/structure/tinyir.jar' to classpath.
```

Then I run:

```
scala> import tinyir._
```

and I receive:

```
<console>:11: error: not found: value tinyir
import tinyir._
          ^
```

Many thanks for any comments.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It's my first post, somehow the code formatting didn't work for me. If anyone knows how to change it, please let me know, so I can make my question more readable. Also open to other suggestions how to improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: You need to add an empty line before the code block, which is indented at least four spaces. I edited it for you. To be able to save the edits, I also needed to change 've to have, while this would have been all right ;-)

Comment: thanks for your edits! I hope someone has an answer to my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:require tinyir is enough
```

I'm assuming you are doing a scala course and trying to use http://www.da.inf.ethz.ch/files/tinyir.jar jar,

remember that Scala uses packages,

```
lnramirez:Downloads lnramirez$ ls -ltrh
-rw-r--r--@  1 lnramirez  1240321454    42K Oct 19 15:43 tinyir.jar
lnramirez:Downloads lnramirez$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_65).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :require tinyir.jar
Added '/Users/lnramirez/Downloads/tinyir.jar' to classpath.

scala> import ch.ethz.dal.tinyir._
import ch.ethz.dal.tinyir._

scala>
```

Comment: you're spot on! thanks very much, it works! I'm very happy to conclude the day on this high. as you correctly assume, it's my first time with scala, it's a course requirement and I don't really have any experience in Java either yet. however, I'm quite eager to learn. could you explain why I had to include the ch.ethz.dal in front of tinyir._ ? is that something to do how the jar was packaged?

Comment: scala relies on java, java modules are defined in packages and they decided their package was ch.ethz.dal.tinyir and actually there are other packages inside that. you had to include it because a class is defined by package + name

is really a longer topic and you should try to understand it better, here some doc:

http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2697/oracle-official-code-standard/9031/naming-conventions#t=201610201602042992057